# Why use @1x image in iOS 8 and higher?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

Why use @1x image in iOS 8 and higher? @1x need for iPhone 3, which not supported iOS higher than 6. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just for the iPAD 2 which is using 1024 × 768 resolution in 1x

This is the only device with 1x resolution for iOS 8+.

In addition to @ KIDdAe's answer, you cant remove 1X icons as all iPhone application can be used in iPad as well.

So it is better to have all images (1x,2x,3x) in the application bundle.

You can have more idea on this link 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

To get all supported device list 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_8#Supported_devices

Please let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: In fact iOS will scale down retina image if non retina is missing. So if you're only keeping non retina in iPhone only app, only for ipad 2 ... I guess removing non retina is still a thing you should do.

Answer (score 1):

iPad 2 is not retina and can run iOS 8+, so if your app support iPad you should keep using non retina image.

If your app is iPhone only, you should remove all not retina image if you have the retina equivalent !

Comment: iPhone only apps are still required to run on iPads (scaled up).

Comment: @JamesP I personnally think that it's not a good decision to keep non retina image in bundle only to support iphone scale on ipad. iOS is intelligent and will scale down retina image for non retina screen.

Comment: I disagree, those devices are getting slower and you're asking them to use more memory than necessary, all to save a couple of MB in the bundle.

Comment: @JamesP It's only personal opinion. But I think you should not think about non officially supported devices (ipad) if it lowers your app optimization. Couple of MB matters when you think about some retina device having only 8GB.

Comment: Watch the WWDC videos on how to create an app that will only download items that are used _on that device_. iPad 2 is officially supported.